Mathematica file shows as a Matlab file
i downloaded a package but I'm having problem since the m-file shows as a Matlab code and not Mathematica code, can someone help how to fix this problem.
I'm using windows 11 Mathematica 14

i already tried many ways but nothing worked.
also, i got the file The lce.m Mathematica package (for Mathematica >7) from https://www.msandri.it/soft.html

the error


Why is the OS saying this is Matlab file prevents you from using the file as Mathematica file and reading it in Mathematica? But you always change the file association to different application in windows.  You must have installed Matlab on your PC before Mathematica, that is why.

@Nasser ok i got it, can i ask one more question please?

Sure. You can update your question in this case with any changes/questions you have.

@Nasser my question is about the example.nb after i open it there is this sentence       SetDirectory["C:/lce_dir"];
<< lce.m

@Nasser i don't know how to change the inside of SetDirectory , i already saved the ice.m in the desktop , i will update the question and post from where i get the file.

@Nasser i want to change it since I'm getting this error when i run it ,Cannot set current directory to C:/lce_dir.

You do not need to change directory or do any of that. Simply type  Get["c:/lce_dir/lce.m"] from any open notebook.  This will read the package. Assuming you have the file lce.m there ofcourse.

@Nasser i did what you said but I'm getting error i uploaded updated picture if you have time can you check it please.

need to correct the file path. it is c:/ not c/ as above.

@Nasser   i'm getting the same error Get: Cannot open C:/lce_dir/lce.m.

is the file lce.m in the folder c:/lce_dir/ on your PC??  did you check?  can you open the file using plain text editor such as notepad?

@Nasser i don't have c:/lce_dir/  on my PC, this is from the original package, I put the lce.m file the desktop after i download it

You need to use the path on your own PC, i.e. where you downloaded the lce.m file to.

@Nasser i think i made it, but I'm having one more error with the code can you check it please thank you for your patience

@Nasser i make an update with a photo of the error I'm getting The sum of the LCEs must be less than or equal to zero. if you have time to check it i really appreciate it.

This is internal error to the package. LCE::pos = "The sum of the LCEs must be less than or equal to zero."; since I am not user of this package, I do not know the cause. It seems there is something not right in the input you are giving it. Try to contact the author of the package or debug the package itself.

@Nasser i think i will figure it out by myself, thank you so much for your help and your patience i really appreciate it.
